# How to click on the list of items in protractor

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor

HTML code

```
<li class="active-result result-selected group-option" data-option-array-index="72">Information Technology and Services</li>
```

While doing automation testing in protractor am not able to click on the particular list item. Using xpath, I can click the list item but without using xpath i have to do.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you please post what you've already tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean ng-click ?

```
    <li ng-click="click(72)" class="active-result result-selected group-option" 
data-option-array-index="72">Information Technology and Services</li>
```

And in the controller, use

```
$scope.click = function(no) { console.info(no +" li clicked") }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="first-input" type="text"/>
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
<input id="second-input" type="text"/>
 <ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
 </ul>
<input id="third-input" type="text"/>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
 </ul>
```

element(by.id('second-input')).element(by.xpath('following-sibling::ul'));

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the item by selecting by css instead of xpath.

```
element.all(by.css('.result-selected')).click();
```

When your element has an ng-click attribute

```
<li ng-click="selected(72)" class="active-result result-selected group-option" 
    data-option-array-index="72">Information Technology and Services</li>
```

Comment: i am new to angular protractor so please help me. i am getting this error.                                                                           UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (426, 433). Other element would receive the click: <li class="group-result">...</li>
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.132)

Answer (score -1):

**Use this method will click the element in list**

---

```
  clickElementInList: function (list, item) {
        list.reduce((result, element) => {
            if (result) return result;
            return element.getText().then((text) => {
                if (text.toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase())) return element;
            });
        }).then((element_found) => {
            if (!element_found) throw new Error(item + " not found");
            this.click(element_found);
        });
    },
```